# Upload MS Word document to Sharepoint without metadata

Tags: sharepoint, file-upload, sharepoint-2010, metadata

Could you advise me what is the best way to handle uploading to SharePoint (2010) MS Word document which already contain metadata added by SharePoint? I face a problem when users get some documents from SharePoint library, modify it and upload them as a new file to the same library. I have a form which opens on doc upload to fill some metadata and those fields on the form are pre-filled with the values previously set on the document by  SharePoint. The biggest problem is that even if the user changes those values, the file is saved with the old ones anyway and a new list item is created also with incorrect (old) values which of course lead to conflits and errors.

I was thinking about clearing the values by hand with an eventreceiver in ItemAdding method by just doing:

```
    public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        properties.AfterProperties["Title"] = String.Empty;
        properties.AfterProperties["Adresat"] = "";
        properties.AfterProperties["Nr_x0020_dziennika"] = "";
        properties.AfterProperties["Budowa"] = "";
        properties.AfterProperties["Osoba_x0020_odpowiedzialna"] = "";
        properties.AfterProperties["Osoba_x0020_do_x0020_wiad"] = "";
        properties.AfterProperties["Komentarz"] = "";
    }
```

but it looks like a nasty workaround and it also strips later versions of document when uploading them in the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a bad solution to your problem if it only applies to new documents.

You could have your event receiver also do a check if there are previous versions by looking at properties.ListItemVersion

And the since the metadata for Office documents is actually stored inside the document, you may need to make some modifications to this solution which actually removes it out of the document:  http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2012/12/remove-sharepoint-metadata-from-ms.html

Comment: Thanks for the input. In ItemAdding there's no ListItem available while uploading the first version of file, but it was sufficient for me to check if the listitem is null.
But I've encountered another problem, that after clearing AfterProperties, some of my columns remain always empty even if they are filled on the form during the upload.
Do you know possibly the reason of this?

Comment: It may have to do with how the metadata was removed.  Instead of removing it, you could try setting it in the document.

Comment: Admittedly, I'm not sure why the metadata is not being updated.  Another test would be to try using ItemAdded instead of ItemAdding and see if that can effect the metadata.